# Confluence starts with Error Code 101: Login required

Tags: installation, apache2, confluence

I installed confluence on my webserver.
I used the instructions from https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html
My vhosts.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.de
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia Off
    <Proxy *>
         Require all granted
    </Proxy> 
    ProxyPass / http://sub.domain.de:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://sub.domain.de:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

My server.xml File looks like this

```
<Server port="8000" shutdown="SHUTDOWN" debug="0">
    <Service name="Tomcat-Standalone">
        <Connector port="8090" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                maxThreads="48" minSpareThreads="10"
                enableLookups="false" acceptCount="10" debug="0" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />
        <Engine name="Standalone" defaultHost="localhost" debug="0">
            <Host name="localhost" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false">
                <Context path="" docBase="../confluence" debug="0" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <!-- Logger is deprecated in Tomcat 5.5. Logging configuration for Confluence is specified in confluence$
                    <Manager pathname="" />
                    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve" threshold="60" />
                </Context>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
        <!--
            To run Confluence via HTTPS:
             * Uncomment the Connector below
             * Execute:
                 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA (Windows)
                 $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA  (Unix)
               with a password value of "changeit" for both the certificate and the keystore itself.
             * Restart and visit https://localhost:8443/
             For more info, see https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Running+Confluence+Over+SSL+or+HTTPS
        -->
<!--
        <Connector port="8090" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25"
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                   acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
                   clientAuth="false" sslProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" SSLEn$
                   URIEncoding="UTF-8" keystorePass="<MY_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD>
                   proxyName="sub.domain.de"
                   proxyPort="8080"
                   "/>
-->
    </Service>
</Server>
```

If i'm trying to open my confluence installation, i get the following response:
{"error":{"code":101,"message":"Login required"}}

Whats wrong?
I am unable to open the installation wizzard on my webbrowser.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: The prerequisites at the link you posted clearly state that the Atlassian applications should be installed and accessible through a web browser before proceeding.  You're asking about opening the installation wizard through Apache.  You haven't met the prerequisites.

Comment: SideNote: The `<Proxy *>` tag there makes no sense, that one is used to forward proxying, thing you are not doing. Remove it.